# How to change the local domain in next.js application?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, next.js14

I want to change the local (development) domain in my Next.js 14 application.
Instead of having something like: "http://localhost:4200" I want to have something like: "https://dev.mydomain.com".

I'm using next.js 14 with the new app router (If it's relevant for some reason).
Also, I'm using nx.dev for managing my repo.

I don't see anything related to that in the docs so I would be happy to have some help here.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible. Next.js development server is a web server that listen to the 127.0.0.1 IP on port 4200 (in your case). It happens that, natively, the name `localhost` is bound by the local DNS resolver of your operating system to the address 127.0.0.1. That's why localhost:4200 works: it targets 127.0.0.1:4200 internally, which is the address that the web server of next.js is bound to. If you want another address to be bound to the same IP you need to configure the DNS resolver of your operating system accordingly.